# Intermittent test failure due to Maximum Stack Depth Reached

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have some tests which usually pass, but every once in a while, all of the tests fail with the following message.  Is there a revision I can make to my tests to avoid this intermittent failure?

```
CanvasIntegrationServiceTest.testSyncAlertsForCases           Fail     System.LimitException: Maximum stack depth reached: 10                  126
    Class.hed.UTIL_CustomSettingsFacade.configSettings: line 143, column 1
    Class.hed.UTIL_CustomSettingsFacade.getOrgSettings: line 114, column 1
    Class.hed.Advancement_Info.setup: line 64, column 1
    Class.hed.Advancement_Info.useAdv: line 148, column 1
    Class.hed.TDTM_Config.getTdtmConfig: line 65, column 1
    Class.hed.TDTM_Config.getClassesToCallForObject: line 139, column 1
    Class.hed.TDTM_TriggerHandler.run: line 68, column 1
    Class.hed.TDTM_Global_API.run: line 61, column 1
    Trigger.hed.TDTM_Contact: line 33, column 1
```

Since all of the tests pass or all fail, and when they fail the stack trace looks the same, I have reasoned that the problem must be in the data setup that is essentially the same for each test.  This is an excerpt from that setup

```
List<Case> cases=createContactsAndCases(3);
...
    public static List<Case> createContactsAndCases(Integer numToCreate) {
        MatriculationTestUtilities.populateCustomSetting();
        //Create N contacts with one case each 

        List<Contact> testContacts = new List<Contact>();

        for (Integer j=0;j<numToCreate; j++) {
            Integer index = math.mod(j,11);
            String[] alpha = new String[] {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'};
            String appendLetter=alpha[index];

            testContacts.add(new Contact(firstname='Test' + appendLetter, lastname='Last'+ appendLetter,RecordTypeId=STUDENT,salc_SIS_ID__c='G'+j));

        }
        insert testContacts;

        List<Contact> insertedContacts = [select Id, FirstName from Contact where lastname like 'Last%'];
        
        
        List<Case> cases=new List<Case>();
        for (Contact c: insertedContacts) {
            Case aCase = new Case(RecordTypeId=ADVISEE);
            
            aCase.ContactId=c.Id;
            aCase.OwnerId=ADVISOR;
            cases.add(aCase);
        }
        insert cases;
        return cases;

    }
```

Comment: It'll help if you [edit] your question to include the code that leads to this error.

Comment: the error suggests a recursion issue in your code and that would be the place to  look - not the test class

Comment: Sounds like I should ask EDA team about this then, thanks.